# Data augmentation in validation

Tags: data-augmentation

I am a little bit confused about the data augmentation. If I perform data augmentation in train dataset, validation dataset should have the same operations?
For example

```
data_transforms = {
'train': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),
'val': transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
]),}
```

Why do we take the 'resize' and 'CenterCrop' operations in 'val' dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since validation data is used to measure how good a trained model is, it should not be changed across different trained models. That is, **we should use a fixed measure to evaluate things**. This is the reason why the augmentation of validation data does not contain any randomness, which exist in the training data augmentation.

SIDE NOTE:

Unlike test data, validation data is used to tune the hyper parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly disagree with the @Yashio Yamauchi's answer. Yes, data augmentation is commonly used in the training dataset to increase the number of the dataset samples, when the dataset is small. **However, there are cases where your validation dataset is also small, so You cannot actually evaluate your model.**

For example, let's say that your task is to recognise Logos on T-Shirts (e.g. Adidas Logo), no matter how they are rotated on an images (e.g. 90 degrees). Then, You will have to use data-augmentations to ensure that your model is fed with rotated t-shirts. However, If you want to measure how well your model identifies "Adidas" when it is rotated 90 degrees, then You will need to have images in your validation dataset that contain rotated t-shirts, as well.

In such case, Data Augmentations could be used once in the validation dataset, before the training happens!